# Expectation of a ratio of random variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value

Suppose $X$~$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Is the following statement correct:  $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{X^2}\right)$ $\ne$ $\frac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}$?

Comment: Many threads here have discussed the distribution of $X/X^2=1/X$: because (no matter what $\mu$ and $\sigma\gt 0$ may be) $X$ has positive density around $X=0$, $1/X$ has an undefined expectation.  That takes care of the left hand side.  Can you evaluate the right hand side?

Comment: Thanks @whuber. Possibility of having undefined expectation is something I did not think through before asking the question. The right hand side is: $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2+\mu^2}$
. My concern was whether the expectation of the ratio of a random variable can be written as the ratio of expectations of that random variable. In order to exclude the possibility of undefined expectation in above example, suppose that r.v. X takes only strictly positive values $x \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ (e.g. Gamma distributed). The inequality would be correct?

Comment: I found a nice relevant answer - [See here:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248472/expectation-on-1-x)

Answer (score 4):

The right hand side of your equality is a finite number (assuming $\sigma > 0$), while the left hand side simplifies to  $\mathbb{E} \frac1X$, so do not exist, see for example [I've heard that ratios or inverses of random variables often are problematic, in not having expectations. Why is that?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299722/ive-heard-that-ratios-or-inverses-of-random-variables-often-are-problematic-in)