# Expected value of E(exp(1/X)) where X~N(0,sigma_x)

Tags: expected-value

I would like to obtain the expected value of $ \mathbb{E}(\exp(1/X))$ where $X$ ~ $N(0,\sigma_x)$

Comment: It doesn't have finite expectation

Answer (score 3):

Because $$\exp(y) \gt \max(0,y)$$ for all numbers $y,$ $$\mathbb E[\exp(1/X)] \gt \mathbb E[1/\max(0,X)].$$ However, the latter is infinite because $X$ has a continuous nonzero density at $0.$  See [I've heard that ratios or inverses of random variables often are problematic, in not having expectations. Why is that?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299722) for a full analysis.

**Therefore $\mathbb E[\exp(1/X)]$ diverges; that is, *it is infinite.***