# F-Distribution: difference between the expected value for a random variable and the expected value of its inverse?

Tags: distributions, expected-value, degrees-of-freedom, chi-squared-distribution, f-distribution

It is known that the expected value of the F-Distribution depends only on the degrees of freedom associated with the Chi-square random variable in the denominator.

In other words, E[1/X] does not equal 1/E[X].

Could someone help me intuitively understand why this is?

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299722/ive-heard-that-ratios-or-inverses-of-random-variables-often-are-problematic-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), as $1/x$ is a convex function. Consider, to gain some intuition, a distribution giving probability mass to only two points, $a$ and $b$. Let $g(x)$ be a convex function. Then,

$$ g(E[x]) = g(p(a)g(a) + p(b)g(b))$$

the value of $g(x)$ at some point $x$ between $a$ and $b$. However,

$$E[g(x)] = p(a)g(a) + p(b)g(b) $$

is a value in the segment from $(a,g(a))$ to $(b,g(b))$ and said segment is ***above*** $g(x)$ (by the convexity of $g(x)$): so $E[g(x)] \ge g(E[x])$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!