# $E\left(\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right)$ under a (standard) Gaussian/Normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

wondering if it's not analytical, are there any bounds that are possible? Appreciate it if any solutions or comments.

Comment: After going back and forth with my (now deleted) comments, I believe the expectation does not exist at all...

Comment: Now I see it. Thanks!

Comment: @B.Liu That is correct, as shown at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299722.  To apply the results, simply notice that $(1+X)^2$ is non-central chi-squared random variable with 1 df.  Because its density grows arbitrarily high near $0,$ its reciprocal has an infinite expectation.