# How to calculate an expected value of this expression?

Tags: expected-value

I have three random variables: $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ and I know their expected values. I want to calculate:

$$E\left[\frac{3-X-Y}{Z}\right].$$

I know that $E\left[\frac{1}{X}\right] \neq \frac{1}{E\left[ X\right]}$ but how can one approach a problem like that?

Comment: It depends on the details.  What do you know about the joint distribution of $(X,Y,Z)$?  If you know nothing, then there's nothing you can do to compute the expectation, because it could be (literally) anything, including undefined or infinite.

Comment: What if it is assumed that the joint distribution of $(X,Y,Z)$ is normal?

Comment: Then, unless it is a degenerate Normal distribution, the fraction can be expressed as a sum of which one term is a ratio of *independent* Normally distributed variables and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299722 shows the expectation is undefined.