# Expected Value / Variance of Gamma to the Negative Integer

Tags: expected-value, gamma-distribution

For random variable $Z$ from a $Gamma(p), p > 0$ distribution we know that the expected value of $E[Z^s]$ is simply the gamma function at $p+s$ divided by the gamma function at $p$, for $p+s$ > 0.

But what if we are interested in calculating $E[Z^{-2}]$ and the variance of $Z^{-2}$ ?
We can just use the same method requiring $p > 2$, but is there a more general way of evaluating in the case that $p < 2$?

Comment: The variance is infinite in all those cases, so there's no need for any calculation.  For a proof of this assertion, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/299765/919.

Comment: Consider $p=1$ (i.e. an exponential random variable).  [Its reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Inverse_exponential_distribution) does not have a mean,  let alone a finite second moment or variance.