Bounding the variance of random variables which solve a linear equation
Consider a matrix $\boldsymbol{M} : \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ where every element $M_{ij}$ is a continuous i.i.d. random variable of unspecified distribution, but with known mean and variance. Consider a similar vector $\vec{v} : \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1}$ of i.i.d. random variables $V_i$, which are uncorrelated with all $M_{ij}$. Finally, consider a set of potentially correlated variates $\Theta_i$ which satisfy
$$
\sum_{j} M_{ji} \Theta_j = V_i,
$$
or equivalently, the linear equation expressed in terms of vector $\vec{\theta}$ containing $\Theta_i$,
$$
\boldsymbol{M} \,  \vec{\theta} = \vec{v}.
$$
I seek to express, approximate, or bound the variance of each $\Theta_i$ in terms of the variances and means of $M_{ij}$ and $V_i$. Alas I am unsure how to begin, and applications of techniques like the Delta method are hampered by my being unable to express the inverse of $\boldsymbol{M}$. In general, $\boldsymbol{M}$ may be non-invertible, in which case I consider approximate $\vec{\theta}$ solutions using TSVD or Tikhonov regularisation.
Any and all ideas are very welcome!

In general the variance is infinite.  To see why, consider the $N=1$ case, where you are taking the ratio of two uncorrelated variables, and ponder the result at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299722.

Bother! In our case, each matrix & vector element is an average of many i.i.d. Bernoulli variates (i.e. each an estimator). For sufficiently many variates, the variance of the determined $\Theta_i$ is small and well-behaved; we never see an element $\Theta_i$ catastrophically far from its mean (never infinite hehe). Does this situation permit bespoke treatment/bounds?

It won't change the mathematical result, but maybe you could reframe the question.  If, for instance, you are estimating variances from data, you could construct confidence intervals for them.  Alternatively, you could inquire about other properties of the distributions, such as IQRs.

We're working in the other direction; trying to reason about how replacing the matrix/vector elements in a linear equation with a sum of Bernoulli variates (with mean = the original element) affects the accuracy of solution $\vec{\theta}$. We ultimately seek to bound the variance of $\vec{\theta}$ in terms of those of $M$ and $\vec{v}$. But it's proving difficult to find statements!
